# Error : ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 azure deployment

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, webpack, msdeploy

I'm using aspnetcore template , with React + Redux and webpack, when im using publish

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and
>   C:\Users\nomorethrow\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\EPWeb\tsconfig.json EPWeb       0

i dont know how to resolve this, in node.js all works well (dotnet run etc), but in visual studio i get error

Comment: i use this template https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

Comment: i think its problem with webpack becouse with gulp all works

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I remove 2 line in project.json. It can deploy

```
"node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
"node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
```

But I have another error when access the deploy version: "Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified StartCore" I don't know it have relation or not ([Cannot run asp.net core, angular 2, server side rendering project in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223432/cannot-run-asp-net-core-angular-2-server-side-rendering-project-in-server))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know why publish treats this information as error and fails but for me the solution was to set silent mode in ts-loader webpack configuration.