# ASP.NET Core 2.0 (Angular) to CloudFoundry

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, cloud-foundry

I am working on an app in CloudFoundry (CF) and I am getting an error when I push my code into CF saying that NodeJs is not installed.

```
[APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories
Current PATH enviroment variable is: /home/vcap/deps/0/bin:/home/vcap/app/bin:/home/vcap/app/node_modules/.bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

I am using the latest CF .NET Core buildpack to push my app with the CLI command below;

```
cf push my-app -k 1GB -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack.git
```

I can't find any information on how to install NodeJs into CF. They said that it should be included when I use the NodeJs buildpack but I can't do that because my app needs the .NET Core buildpack. Unless there's a way to use 2 buildpacks?

Comment: I don't know if this will necessarily resolve your issue, but you should never run from the master branch of a buildpack.  It's not stable and will change whenever code get's checked into it.  That could include things which break your app deployment.  Instead, you should either use one of the buildpack's included with CF or point to a specific release of the buildpack like this `-b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack#v1.0.28`.  The `#<branch-or-tag>` is how you indicate the stable release or branch to use.

Comment: If that doesn't help, include the full output from running `cf stage`.  It's critical to include all of that so we can see exactly what happened when the buildpack ran.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll do that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For starters, check out the [.Net Steeltoe project](https://steeltoe.io/) for deploying .Net apps on PCF (there's an invitation for the slack channel on that page also).

Additionally, consider packaging your app as a [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), which will assure that the correct .Net runtime is included in the build.

As to your buildpack question, yes - you can use [multiple buildpacks](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html), including both the [.Net Core](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/dotnet-core/index.html) and [Node.js](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/node/index.html) buildpacks. That should eliminate the missing Node error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

While it's a workaround, you can remove the dependency on NodeJS unless you really need the server side pre-rendering functionality.

The issue stems from the inclusion of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices

See: [Do I need to install Node.js on Production Server to host Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389131/do-i-need-to-install-node-js-on-production-server-to-host-angular-2) for further info.

The relevant code parts to remove are:

#### Views/_ViewImports.cshtml

remove `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`

#### Startup.cs

Remove `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;`

Remove (from `public void Configure(...)`)

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

I was planning to log an issue on the [dotnet-core-buildpack repo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/issues) as well.

Also, You may be able to build your own buildpack that includes it, but I'm pretty green w/ PCF, so I haven't travelled that road yet.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was as follows: Running these commands resulted in the following errors in the log:

```
dotnet new angular
npm install
dotnet build
[add manifest.yml to project]
cf push
```

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.
>
> [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
>
> Current PATH enviroment variable is: /home/vcap/deps/0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
>
> Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

**Removing the lines of code** in `Startup.cs` and `Views\_ViewImports.cshtml` allows this sample project to push and run successfully in Cloud Foundry.